# Editing an included file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a file called Head.inc which my index uses for the design of the page. which looks like this:

```
Name-----Marks----Age----Subject

Bob-------67------13------Maths

James-----89------15------English
```

But i need the files to be sorted by the subject:

```
----------Maths--------

Name----Marks----Age

Bob-------67------13

---------English------

Name----Marks----Age

James------84----15
```

This is my header.inc file:

```
<title>Contacts</title>

<!-- custom style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

<!-- font awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- tynymce -->
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom js -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="js/custom.js"></script>


<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Comment: First of all, you have no code to support the php/mysql tags.

Comment: Please note I am still new to php and html and dont know how CSS or javascript works yet. I found this script on another website while googling for a tutorial

Comment: @Fred-ii- the rest of my code is on my index.php page but I was told by my lecturer that I need to edit something in this head.inc file

Comment: E.g.: a simple loop in PHP

Comment: @Strawberry iv read about that but where would I put the loop? iv tried group by and everything else I could and my index.php layout doesnt change.

Comment: Typically, you might return the data set ordered by, say, subject, marks, age. In PHP, you could then build a little loop that assigned marks to a named div, and the other details to 'sub-divs'. Then you could use a simple html script to re-sort the results to suit. Here's an example of using javascript to sort stuff - but there are billions of examples out there... http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/zGZywM

Comment: @Strawberry you lost me good sir...confused